# Mimic Python (pure) virtual functions like C#

Tags: c#, python, abstract-class, virtual-functions, pure-virtual

What is the best way in Python to mimic virtual and pure virtual functions like in C#?

Currently I use a schema like:

```
class AbstractClass(object):
    '''Abstract class'''
    def __init__(self):
        assert False, 'Class cannot be instantiated'

    def _virtual_init(self):
        print 'Base "constructor"'

    def pure_virtual_function(self):
        assert False, 'Pure virtual function should be derived'

    def virtual_function(self):
        print 'Base: virtual function'

class Derived1(AbstractClass):
    '''All functions derived'''
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Derived1: constructor'
        AbstractClass._virtual_init(self)

    def pure_virtual_function(self):
        print 'Derived1: pure virtual function'

    def virtual_function(self):
        print 'Derived1: virtual function'

class Derived2(AbstractClass):
    '''Pure virtual method missing.'''
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Derived2: constructor'
        AbstractClass._virtual_init(self)

    def virtual_function(self):
        print 'Derived3: virtual function'

class Derived3(AbstractClass):
    '''Virtual method missing (use base class)'''
    def __init__(self):
        print 'Derived3: constructor'
        AbstractClass._virtual_init(self)

    def pure_virtual_function(self):
        print 'Derived3: pure virtual function'


# ab = AbstractClass() # Gives error -> OK

print 'DERIVED 1'    
dv1 = Derived1()
dv1.pure_virtual_function()
dv1.virtual_function()

print 'DERIVED 2'    
dv2 = Derived2()
# dv2.pure_virtual_function() # Gives error: Pure virtual function should be derived -> OK
dv2.virtual_function()

print 'DERIVED 3'    
dv3 = Derived3()
# dv3.pure_virtual_function() # Gives error: Pure virtual function should be derived -> OK
dv3.virtual_function()
```

I get as output:

```
DERIVED 1
Derived1: constructor
Base "constructor"
Derived1: pure virtual function
Derived1: virtual function
DERIVED 2
Derived2: constructor
Base "constructor"
Derived3: virtual function
DERIVED 3
Derived3: constructor
Base "constructor"
Derived3: pure virtual function
Base: virtual function
```

However my specific questions are:

1. Is there a more elegant way to define an abstract base class in Python (2.7)?
     The above solution only gives an error at run time (not e.g. with pylint)
     There is no 'abstract' keyword in Python afaik.
2. Is there a more elegant way to define a pure virtual method in Python (2.7)?
     Again, the above solution only gives an error at run time.
3. Is there a more elegant way to define a virtual method in Python (2.7)?
     No checking is needed, but there is no keyword like 'virtual' in Python afaik.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not completely familiar with these design patterns ... But reading this code reminds me of the `abc` module.  You might want to have a look there and see if it provides the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: You're never gonna get more than a run time error. There are no compile time checks to speak of, apart from validity of syntax. (Though you could try to *teach* pylint to perform such checks for you.) Better yet, **forget** about all those neat design tools. Just *do* it. Define a couple of classes with compatible interfaces but no inheritance, pass instances around, etc. without trying to get the computer to enforce such invariants. You appear to be thinking in C#/Java. That results in awful Python output, just like a Python mindset would produce horrible C#/Java code.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Each language has its own way of doing things. You don't need this in python.

Comment: I think inheritance is a very nice way of designing software and it is not really nicely implemented in Python ... but as @mgilson already notices, there is a nice abc module for overcoming parts of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what exactly do you mean when you ask about virtual methods, as in Python all methods are virtual. And I'm also not sure why you are using `_virtual_init` instead of `__init__`… does simply renaming a method buy you something?

*Update:* Ah, I've got an idea. You probably did this to prohibit instantiation of your base class still keeping initialisation functionality in it. The answer here is: forcing things is not *pythonic*. Just document that this class is abstract (and probably call it `AbstractSmth`).

Speaking about run-times errors. Python is a *dynamic* language, so, well, that's how it works. A common idiom is raising `NotImplementedError` in `__init__` to show that your class is abstract (and the same is true for abstract (pure virtual) methods). You can also have a look at [`abc`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) as it does what you want: it prohibits instantiation of abstract classes. But I also strongly suggest reading [PEP-3119](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3119/) to understand what Abstract Base Classes *are* and what they *are not*.

AFAIK, raising `NotImplementedError` is enough for pylint to understand that your class/method is abstract.

Comment: I'm using _virtual_init instead of __init__ because I don't want users to instantiate an abstract class directly. But the abc module overcomes this problem.

Documenting is less good than enforcing.

And I know Python is a dynamic language, the NotImplementedError is indeed better than an assert. Thanks for th PEP-3119 link.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AbstractBaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        if self.__class__.__name__ == 'AbstractBaseClass':
            raise NotImplementedError("Can't instantiate AbstractBaseClass")

class DerivedClass(AbstractBaseClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # ...
```

This example shows that derived classes (that have a different `__class__.__name__` member) can be instantiated, and inherit the attributes provided by AbstractBaseClass.  But if AbstractBaseClass gets instantiated directly, the `NotImplementedError` exception will be thrown.

Comment: Add some comments to your answer